# VLC does not start in Ubuntu 14.04 because of Qt error

Tags: 14.04, vlc, qt

This is the error I get trying to open vlc

```
VLC media player 2.1.4 Rincewind (revision 2.1.4-0-g2a072be)
[0x9e37910] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0x9ec11d8] skins2 interface error: no suitable dialogs provider found (hint: compile the qt4 plugin, and make sure it is loaded properly)
[0x9ec11d8] skins2 interface error: cannot instantiate qt4 dialogs provider
[0x9ec11d8] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.1.4 Rincewind
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
```

I tried completely uninstalling and re-installing vlc, tried resetting config, but the same error remains

I followed the answers of the below two questions, but it didn't work

[VLC completely stopped working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457639/vlc-completely-stopped-working)

[upgraded to 14.04 LTS, VLC is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/555830/upgraded-to-14-04-lts-vlc-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is with QT. Try reinstalling it. (or installing if not yet).

sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev

Comment: Please include more details to this answer. Like how to reinstall or install QT.

Comment: tried re-installing QT, but I still get the same error